# Get the percentage of a number with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

So I am creating a web app and I get some data.

There are points you have now (now=284), and total points (total=1000). So, The difference between them is dif=716.

How do I use javascript to turn the difference into a percentage value, for example, 32% or whatever?

Thanks

Comment: [http://www.helpingwithmath.com](http://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/percentages/per_calculating.htm)

Comment: If the difference is `716` and the total is `1000`, why is the difference `32%` when turned into a percentage value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a math question, not programming, but you ask for javascript here you are an example:

```js
var value = 249;
var total = 1000;

var calcPercent = function(v, t) {
  return 100*v/t;
};

alert(calcPercent(value, total)+"%");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var total = 1000,
subtract = 284;
var differencePercentage = ((total - subtract) / total) * 100; // 71.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple math would be

```
var now = 284;
var total = 1000;
console.log( "percentage is " + (now* 100/total) );
console.log( "Negative percentage is " + (100-(now* 100/total)) );
```

Comment: (Why call `parseFloat` on something that's already a number? Even if you're getting a value from a form, better to call it only on that value.)

Comment: @DaveNewton made the correction

Answer (score 1):

```js
(function(){
  var now = 284;
  var total = 1000;

  var difference = ((total - now) / total) * 100;
  
  alert(difference);
})()
```